# Cucumber can't find Ruby step definitions (windows)

Tags: cucumber

**Please, tell me why features doesn't use step definition?**

1) feature\test.feature

```
Feature: guru99 Demopage Login

In order to Login in Demopage we have to enter login details

Scenario: Register On Guru99 Demopage without email

Given I am on the Guru99 homepage

When enter blank details for Register

Then error email shown
```

2)feature\step_definitions\test_steps.rb

```
require 'watir-webdriver'

require 'colorize'

browser = Watir::Browser.new

Given (/^I am on the Guru99 homepage$/)do

browser.goto "http://demo.guru99.com"

end

When (/^enter blank details for Register$/)do

browser.text_field(:name,"emailid").set(" ")

browser.button(:name,"btnLogin").click

end

Then (/^error email shown$/)do

puts " Email is Required".red

browser.close

end
```

3) Run in Start command prompt with ruby

```
cucumber features\test.feature
```

[Start command prompt with ruby screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1pgb.png)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your command has "feature*s*" while your folder is "feature" with no ending "s".  Does that help?